# MATLAB load mat-file with wildcard (*) into current workspace

Tags: matlab

I wrote a function to load mat-files with wildcards in them into a struct, by using [`dir`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html) to catch the wildcards and then invoking [`load`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/load.html). This is the function:

```
function S = loadw(varargin)
%LOADW Load variables from file into workspace, with wildcard (*) in file name

filename = varargin{1};

if(ismember('*', filename))
    [pathstr, ~, ext] = fileparts(filename);
    if(isempty(pathstr))
        pathstr = '.';
    end
    if(~strcmp(ext, '.mat'))
        filename = [filename '.mat'];
    end
    dirFiles = dir(filename);
    if(isempty(dirFiles))
        error(['Unable to read file ''' filename ''': no such file or directory.']);
    elseif(numel(dirFiles) == 1)
        varargin{1} = [pathstr filesep dirFiles(1).name];
        S = load(varargin{:});
    else
        S = cell(numel(dirFiles), 1);
        for iFile = 1:numel(dirFiles)
            varargin{1} = [pathstr filesep dirFiles(iFile).name];
            S{iFile} = load(varargin{:});
        end
    end
else
    S = load(varargin{:});
end
```

This works well, however it can only load a file into a struct, and not into the caller workspace as `load` does.
How can I modify this function to set the variables in the caller workspace?

I thought about using [`assignin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to do this but this means I first load the variables into the function workspace and then transfer them to the caller workspace. I would prefer a method that does not require declaring the variables twice. Is this possible without re-implementing `load`? Or, perhaps, is there no overhead in declaring the variables twice, so that using `assignin('caller',...)` would actually be an efficient solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am convinced that the only options are either to load the files inside the function and then use `assignin('caller',...)`, or to use `evalin('caller', 'load(...);')`. Between these I choose the latter, as I think avoiding declaring the variables twice merits suffering the drawbacks of an `eval` function. This is my function now:

```
function S = loadw(varargin)
%LOADW Load variables from file into workspace, with wildcard (*) in file name

filename = varargin{1};

if(ismember('*', filename))
    [pathstr, ~, ext] = fileparts(filename);
    if(isempty(pathstr))
        pathstr = '.';
    end
    if(~strcmp(ext, '.mat'))
        filename = [filename '.mat'];
    end
    dirFiles = dir(filename);
    if(isempty(dirFiles))
        error(['Unable to read file ''' filename ''': no such file or directory.']);
    elseif(numel(dirFiles) == 1)
        varargin{1} = [pathstr filesep dirFiles(1).name];
        if(nargout > 0)
            S = load(varargin{:});
        else
            strLoadCommand = ['load(''' strjoin(varargin, ''', ''') ''');'];
            evalin('caller', strLoadCommand);
        end
    else
        if(nargout > 0)
            S = cell(numel(dirFiles), 1);
        end
        for iFile = 1:numel(dirFiles)
            varargin{1} = [pathstr filesep dirFiles(iFile).name];
            if(nargout > 0)
                S{iFile} = load(varargin{:});
            else
                strLoadCommand = ['load(''' strjoin(varargin, ''', ''') ''');'];
                evalin('caller', strLoadCommand);
            end
        end
    end
else
    if(nargout > 0)
        S = load(varargin{:});
    else
        strLoadCommand = ['load(''' strjoin(varargin, ''', ''') ''');'];
        evalin('caller', strLoadCommand);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do the line

```
S = load(varargin{:});
```

It will load the variables in the file as struct elements of `S`, or `S{iFile}` as appropriate. If you don't want this, if you just want the variables to go directly into the workspace, you can skip the assignment to `S`

```
load(varargin{:});
```

I generally prefer to avoid loading variables directly into the workspace as you can never be sure what variables are in a file and what it could do to your workspace.

So as an alternative approach, if this is a concern, once you've loaded the variables into `S` you could then write another block that goes through the struct, pulls out the field names (using the `fieldnames` function) and then reassigns the `S.(fieldname)` member to `fieldname` directly, after having checked it doesn't already exist in the workspace (using `exist(fieldname, 1)`).

You'd do the assignment itself using `eval`. Note that Mathworks recently introduced dynamic field referencing for structs and [they recommend this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/13/use-dynamic-field-references/) over `eval` in a lot of cases but I think this use case (assigning to a variables named for the field name) still calls for `eval`.

Comment: I want to assign the variables in the workspace which _calls_ the function `loadw`, just as they are assigned when calling `load`. I could iterate over field names and use `assignin('caller',...)` (rather than `evalin`. I know `eval` and `evalin` should be avoided and usually can be), but this means I declare the variables twice, as I wrote: one time when I load them into the function workspace and a second time when I assign them to the caller workspace. I want to know if this can be avoided.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed that. You could modify the function so that it returned only a list of complete filepaths which you then iterate over and load in the calling workspace. There is also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1823668/is-there-a-way-to-push-a-matlab-workspace-onto-a-stack which isn't exactly what you're asking but has some neat tricks that might be modifiable.